# TLP Error: battery charge thresholds/discharge/recalibrate not available. in RedmiBook

Tags: 22.04, tlp

I have a RedmiBook laptop running 22.04. I started noticing that it overheats when plugged in, so decided to run tlp, but running recalibrate gives me the following error:

```
Error: battery charge thresholds/discharge/recalibrate not available.
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

No way. These features are not supported on RedmiBooks because there is no kernel driver for them.

https://linrunner.de/tlp/settings/bc-vendors.html